# Can i use LINQ to populate an ObservableCollection of ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, linq

I have two classes and am trying to create an `ObservableCollection<ClassA>`, so it will basically be a tree structure as this parent `ObservableCollection` will have sub collection which is of type `ClassB`, My question is:

Can I use a LINQ query to get the `ObservableCollection<ClassB>` and then add it to the `ClassA`'s `ObservableCollection`. So it's basically subitems(`ClassB`) being added to the parent but the subitems(`ClassB`) also have subitems(`ObservableCollection<ClassB>` in `ClassB`)

```
public ClassA
{
    ObservableCollection<ClassB> classBItems = new ObservableCollection<ClassB>
    string name = "Something";

}

public ClassB
{
    ObservableCollection<ClassB> classBSubItems = new ObservableCollection<ClassB>
    string name = "Something";
    bool IsEnabled = false;

}
```

So the structure will be something like this,

```
ParentA
-Child1
-Child2
   -Child3
     -Child4
   -Child5
```

To insert Child4 into this structure, Can I use LINQ to query the `ObservableCollection`? If so, how? I need to add this item to the Child3

Comment: You show your desired structure, but what is the original structure from which we will query to build the new structure?  Querying is more about the source structure.

Comment: My data is flat, The parents will go into ObservableCollection<ClassA> parentCollection, When i come across an item which happens to be a child of something, I want to query parentCollection to add this item as a child(into the observablecollection<classB>)

Comment: Updated the question with the structure

Comment: You need two data structures, a source and a destination.  I see one data structure represented as classes, and then an outline view describing that same data source.

Comment: Okay, Lets just look at the structure then, Can I use LINQ to query ParentA to add Child4 to Child3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not completely sure where child4 is coming from but based on your above structure this will get you Child3.

```
        var child3 = observableOfClassA
            .SelectMany(a => a.classBItems) // flattens list to all classBItems
            .SelectMany(b => b.classBSubItems) // flattens list to classBItems.classBSubItems
            .Where(bSub => bSub.name == "child3s Name goes here")  // replace with your where clause
            .FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use composite pattern  . Take a look into.the pattern mentioned in http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern , also you can change the list type as given in the example to any type which accepts collection(even observable collection too)